# How can i hide view in Listview according to the position

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I have a relative layout and i want to hide and show on button click (for each item of list view).

Adapter.java

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    inflate list_items.xml

    set data


on button click
            if view is hidden 
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });
    return cView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified some of your code. try this, may be it works for you.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

inflate list_items.xml

set data

//Layout which i want to hide and show
        barRL = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layout20);
        button= (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button); // to click button 

        if (button is not visible) {
                barRL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
                barRL.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        //Button to hide and show layout
        ImageView arrowUpDown =           (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.arrowupdown);

        arrowUpDown.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                if (arrowUpDownis not visible) {
                    arrowUpDownis.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 } else {
                    arrowUpDownis.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                 }
    notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            });
            return convertView;
        }
```

and don't set visibility of button in xml.

Answer (score 0):

Just add notifydatasetchanged() to your code.

```
 ArrayList <Boolean> statusList;//initialise it in array as true for all the elements

 @Override
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

inflate list_items.xml

set data

//Layout which i want to hide and show
barRL = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layout20);

if (statusList.get(position)) {
            barRL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            barRL.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
//Button to hide and show layout
ImageView arrowUpDown = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.arrowupdown);

arrowUpDown.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
if (view is not visible) {
           statusList.set(position,true);
        } else {
             statusList.set(position,false);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
return convertView;
}
```

Comment: for that you need to create a boolean list which contains the status of all the bars which are visible and which are hidden. Then on getView() you need to make it visible or hide on the basis of that boolean list.